# Determining if an offset is in between line numbers?

Tags: java, eclipse, range, offset, viewport

I need to determine if a given selection is in between a start line and an end line.
I have an `ILineRange` and a given offset within the viewport of eclipse. (I need to know, if the selection (from a remote party) was made within the current viewport of the local user. Unfortunately, I cannot get an `ILineRange` from the selection. I must rely on getOffset() and getLength()...
Anyone has an idea? 
I think there is not a clean solution for this, as the offset (or the characters per line vary (new line lines or a big block of comment).

Comment: When you say "viewport", you mean the eclipse output viewport?

Comment: with "viewport" I mean the visible lines of the currently opened editor window for the local user.

Comment: neither of the 2 given answers apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion between positions and offsets can be done with IDocument's API (methods around getLine*()). (I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but I do hope that this is helpful information.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check if that [`org.eclipse.linuxtools.dataviewers.annotatedsourceeditor.STOverviewRuler`  class](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/technology/org.eclipse.linuxtools/gcov/trunk/org.eclipse.linuxtools.dataviewers.annotatedsourceeditor/src/org/eclipse/linuxtools/dataviewers/annotatedsourceeditor/STOverviewRuler.java) deals with the same kind of problem you have.
Something *along the lines* of:

```
if (ANNOTATION_HEIGHT_SCALABLE) {
  int numbersOfLines= document.getNumberOfLines(annotationOffset, annotationLength);
  // don't count empty trailing lines
  IRegion lastLine= document.getLineInformationOfOffset(annotationOffset + annotationLength);
  if (lastLine.getOffset() == annotationOffset + annotationLength) {
    numbersOfLines -= 2;
    hh= (numbersOfLines * size.y) / maxLines + ANNOTATION_HEIGHT;
    if (hh < ANNOTATION_HEIGHT)
      hh= ANNOTATION_HEIGHT;
    } else
      hh= ANNOTATION_HEIGHT;
  }
  fAnnotationHeight= hh;

  int startLine= textWidget.getLineAtOffset(annotationOffset - visible.getOffset());
                        yy= Math.min((startLine * size.y) / maxLines, size.y - hh);
```